# Проблема с удаленным отлаживанием WinDbg

Tags: visual-studio, отладка, tcp, windbg, отладчик

Я изучаю механизм создания драйверов и у меня присутствует виртуальная машина в Virtual Box. Столкнулся с проблемой удаленной отладки в WinDbg, а именно зависание после попытки подключения к удаленному отладчику (см. далее).

При настройке отладчика руководствовался [статьей с MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode-).

Соответственно вот лог подключения:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22621.755 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using NET for debugging
Opened WinSock 2.0
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to target 192.168.1.7 on port 50000 on local IP 192.168.1.6.
You can get the target MAC address by running .kdtargetmac command.
Connected to Windows 10 19041 x64 target at (Sun Feb 12 23:42:06.426 2023 (UTC + 3:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Kernel Debugger connection established.
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff805`82400000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff805`8302a2d0
Debug session time: Sun Feb 12 23:42:04.498 2023 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:16:20.458
Shutdown occurred at (Sun Feb 12 23:42:16.758 2023 (UTC + 3:00))...unloading all symbol tables.
Using NET for debugging
Opened WinSock 2.0
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to target 192.168.1.7 on port 50000 on local IP 192.168.1.6.
You can get the target MAC address by running .kdtargetmac command.
Connected to Windows 10 19041 x64 target at (Sun Feb 12 23:42:27.159 2023 (UTC + 3:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Kernel Debugger connection established.

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`70e00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`71a2a2d0
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:04.455
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
```

**Системы отвечают друг другу на `ping`*

И соответственно при попытке подключения - ответ не поступает. Нигде информации по поводу данной ошибки (по моему мнению) я не нашел. Прошу помощи тут.

UPD1: Строки из дебаггера Visual Studio при развертывании драйвера на удаленной машине

```
Deployment may take a few minutes...
Could not connect to the remote computer for deployment.
```

При этом никаких ошибок на стороне сервера не высвечивается, только тут

Comment: Вы пишите *"при попытке подключения - ответ не поступает"*, а в логе написано *"Kernel Debugger connection established."*

Comment: Наверное не так сформулировал. Вроде пишет, что подключение установлено, но когда пытаюсь начать отладку, то ничего не получается

Comment: *"ничего не получается"* не является описанием проблемы, рассказывайте, что вы там пытаетесь и что происходит

Comment: Я добавил все что имеется.

Comment: Так проблема оказывается с развертыванием драйвера на удаленной машине. Вот это поворот.

Comment: Я пытаюсь развернуть драйвер на удаленной машине. Когда я нажимаю образно "Развернуть" на своем основном компьютере, то происходит то, что описано в UPD1 (данная ошибка высвечивается на основном), а на виртуалке ничего не происходит просто.

Comment: Стоит рассказывать не "образно", а конкретно, чтобы читающие могли воспроизвести у себя заявленное поведение.